# Specifying log file for a scheduled powershell script

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks

I have created a scheduled task in windows to run a powershell script at specific time. As you can see, in the action page, I have specified powershell path as the program and my script as the argument. The scheduled task works fine.

[image]

I would like to include my own log file that prints the output of my script there. How can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a redirection to redirect the output of your powershell script in a file.

However, redirection not always work perfectly when using directly powershell.

So you can use cmd.exe to call powershell and redirect the global outpout to a log file.

I propose you the following parameters for your scheduled task :

Program/script : `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe`

Add arguments : `/c "powershell.exe PATH_OF_YOUR_PS_SCRIPT.ps1" > PATH_OF_LOG_FILE.log`

The symbol `>` is used to redirect the output of the command to the file next to it.

Answer (score 1):

Try
`Start-Transcript`
or
`Start-Transcript -Path c:\temp\log.txt -Append`
on the beginning of your .ps1 file and
`Stop-Transcript`
in the end

It will start logging all output + some additional information.
https://4sysops.com/archives/powershell-transcript-record-a-session-to-a-text-file/